# Using Paypal to purchase access code

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have a simple windows application (C++) that I would like to sell.  The user downloads the full application which runs for 2 weeks.  At the end of that time, the user must buy an access code ($1 - $5) to continue using the application.

The simplest way I've come up with for doing this is to have the application generate a UUID which is written into the registry.  The application generates the access code based off the UUID.  I would like to pass the access code to Paypal when the user initiates a purchase.  If the purchase is successful, I would like Paypal to give the access code to the user (e.g. in an email confirming the purchase).  Finally, the user will type the access code into the application to unlock it.

1) If someone has an easier way to do this, please send me an example.  My requirements are only that the process require some detailed knowledge to hack (e.g. knowledge of a packet sniffer for my scheme above).  (if my application becomes popular enough that someone wants to devote the time to hack it, I will be ecstatic).

2) What I have tried to implement the scheme above:
I have use the directions [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/ht_test-pps-buttons/) to generate a paypal button for a purchase.  I can click on the button and make a purchase using the sandbox.  What I have been unable to do is a) add new hidden data to this button, and b) find a way for paypal to present that data back to the user on a completed transaction.  (There is probably a way for me to do this by having a site that does the paypal ipn stuff found [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/))

The paypal ipn stuff just seems awfully complicated for something that I would think a lot of applications want to do.  What I am hoping is that someone can point out a simpler way to do this with example code.

This is my first time using paypal as a merchant (in case that wasn't obvious).

Here is the sandbox-based button that I have from paypal.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="SOMETHING">
<input type="hidden" name="machine_id" value="PASSCODE">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

In this example, I was trying to send my passcode in the machine_id field.  I can't figure out how to get paypal to send this back to my buyer.

Thanks.
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use your own variables.

Try this    `<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="PASSCODE">`

custom  -   Pass-through variable for your own tracking purposes, which buyers do not see.

Or see list of all variables
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HF00TZS

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had seen the machine_id in a list somewhere of known values -- apparently not.  Is there a way to pass this custom value back to the user without implementing ipn?

Comment: May be you create a notify url? notify_url The URL to which PayPal posts information about the payment, in the form of Instant Payment Notification messages. http://yourserver?machine_id=PASSCODE